# "if i is not value" is ignored if value is 257 or greater in list with range()

Tags: python, list, range

I'd like to fill a list with numbers from 0 to 999, except a certain number. But it looks like the certain number can be from 0 to 256 only; if it's anything over 257 or greater, "if i is not ..." part is ignored. Would someone explain why this is so in Python (both 2.x and 3.x)?

```
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i is not 255]; len(l)
999
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i is not 256]; len(l)
999
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i is not 257]; len(l)
1000
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i is not 258]; len(l)
1000
```

Comment: This would be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/pythons-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Answer (score 3):

`is` tests whether two values are *the same value*, not whether they're *equal*.  Python uses "singleton" values for small integers, but larger integers are a new object every time.

Don't use `is` for anything other than `None`, unless you are absolutely sure what you're doing.  Use `==`/`!=`.

I [wrote about this](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/) once.

Answer (score 1):

Test equality with `==` rather than `is` and inequality with `!=` instead of `is not`.

```
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i is not 257]; len(l)
1000
>>> l = [i for i in range(1000) if i != 257]; len(l)
999
```